# Is it possible to create site collection after creating new content database in Sharepoint 2019 CSOM (C#)?

Tags: csom, site-collection, content-database, 2019

I'm working on SharePoint 2019 environment.

I have just created site collection programmatically (CSOM) using [MSDN Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom/)

However, I want to create a content database through CSOM and point this newly created Content DB for creating above new site collection.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't create a content database through CSOM.

Comment: Is it possible via CSOM powershell?

Comment: no, you need server code.